# combine date and time variables for mysqli datetime field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

i tried something from a similar question here on stack overflow but its still not working.

i have a variable $date and $time and i need to get them both into the database in one date time field
0000-00-00 00:00:00  for the date i use the jquery ui datepicker  and i submit the values through javascript to php to sanitize and insert into database.
when i alert the code i get this 2013-12-07 08:00:00  so i dont understand why its not working  i use this code.

jquery  datepicker

```
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0, maxDate: "+14D" }); 
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", 'yy-mm-dd' );
```

});

php

```
$sdate = strtotime($_POST['date']);
$stime = strtotime($_POST['time']);
$combined = $sdate. $stime;
```

its inserting everything well into the database table but the date time.

any good ideas someone??

Comment: Why are you using strtotime on the values? Are you aware what that function returns?

Comment: because im  new in this. and i have now idea what would be better   thats why im asking some people who have more skills in this.

Comment: Well your first step should always be reading up on what a function does in the manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strtotime()` will return a UNIX timestamp, not a formatted date.

```
if (isset($_POST['date'] && isset($_POST['time']))) {

    $combined = $_POST['date'].' '.$_POST['time'];
    if (strtotime($combined) === false) {

        //You use a try catch if you wanted
        die('Incorrect Date/Time');
    }    
}
```

Here I'm using only using `strtotime()` to validate the datetime.

Hope this helps!

Comment: do you think there is a better way instead of using strtotime()?

Comment: There are a few different ways to do it, but this is just a basic way to make sure you're that it is a date. I'm not actually using `strtotime()` for what's going into the db though, just validation.